# Android HttpCleint works on 2.2 but not on 4

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a method (below) to get data from web services in my android program. It works fine with Android 2.2.  But in 4.x it throws an exception with message "Error Requesting API".  Not sure which part is causing the exception in my code and why only in 4.x  Can someone give me some pointers?

```
        public static synchronized String performHTTPRequest(HttpUriRequest request)
                throws ApiException, ParseException, IOException {
            HttpClientWrapper cli=new HttpClientWrapper();
            HttpClient client;
            try {
                client=cli.getClient();
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                // Check if server response is valid
                StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine() ;

            if (status.getStatusCode() != HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
                throw new ApiException("Invalid response from server: " + status.toString());
            }
            return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }  catch (Exception cnrce) {
            throw new ApiException("Error requesting API:");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you knew the details of the causing exception.. You should add to your ApiException the cause (the underlying exception) so that you can trace the problem.

Comment: Thanks akash and Matt for your answers/comments.  After akash's suggestion I tried few things an noticed that if I make my targetSdkVersion="8" in manifest, the app works in versions 3 and above.  (NetworkOnMainThreadException in not generated in this case I assume).  I am working to make it an async task.  Once done, shall  post my working code (with async task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4.0 or the verions above honeycomb you can not perform any http request on ui thread.
You need to perform these in asynctask.
EDIT:
[Documentation](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

[Code example for asynctask](http://www.adilmughal.com/2012/07/android-networkonmainthread-exception.html)

Comment: Thank you akash.  Do you have any sample code that can help me in making it asynctask?  Or any document that can help?. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks akash.  Your links for documentation and code examples are very good.