# Sending JSON From Android to PHP

Tags: android, json

I've been struggling a bit on sending JSON objects from an application on android to a php file (hosted locally). The php bit is irrelevant to my issue as wireshark isn't recording any activity from my application (emulation in eclipse/ADK) and it's almost certainly to do with my method of sending:

```
      try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("id", "5");
        json.put("time", "3:00");
        json.put("date", "03.04.12");
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        //
        //String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/sample1/webservice2.php?" + 
        //             "json={\"UserName\":1,\"FullName\":2}";
        String url = "http://localhost/datarecieve.php";

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes(
                "UTF8")));
        request.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I've modified this from an example I found, so I'm sure I've taken some perfectly good code and mangled it. I understand the requirement for multi-threading so my application doesn't hang and die, but am unsure about the implementation of it. Would using Asynctask fix this issue, or have I missed something else important?

Thankyou for any help you can provide.

Comment: are you getting any response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using emulator to test the code, `localhost` refers to the emulated environment. If you need to access the php hosted on your computer, you need to use the IP 10.0.2.2 or the LAN IP such as 192.168.1.3.  Check [Referring to localhost from the emulated environment](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias)

You can refer to [Keeping Your App Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) to learn about running your long running operations in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Much appreciated. I imagine if i had run it on an actual device the issues would have been the same then.

Comment: Alright, I believe it's quasi-working now, I've surrounded my code snippet in asynctask, though I'm struggling to work out what types .execute() needs.  new DataSendTask().execute(); gets called in near the beginning of the app, but of course doesnt compile. Any help?

Comment: In an actual device, you need to use the LAN IP if the computer is in the same subnet. If it is in the internet cloud, you can use the public IP/hostname.  Regarding your second comment, can you please post a new question with the AsyncTask code? That will help others also to have a look into it and offer assistance.

Comment: I got it to work, I might clean up the code and post it up with the php. Should I just edit this post when i do? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you should use asynctask or thread, because in higher versions of android it doesn't allow long running task like network operations from ui thread.

[here is the link for more description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352193/android-httpcleint-works-on-2-2-but-not-on-4/14352219#14352219)